# Solving overdetermined, well posed, linear system of PDEs

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let $f=f(u,v)$ be a (given) solution of the following PDE,

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u\partial v}=f,\label{1}\tag{$*$}
\end{equation}
$$

and consider the overdetermined system(s) of PDEs

$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}=f\cos\left(u-v\right)\\
\\
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\sin\left(u-v\right)\\
\\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}=f\sin\left(u-v\right)\\
\\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}=-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cos\left(u-v\right).
\end{cases}
$$

Since $f$ solves \eqref{1} it is guaranteed that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial u\partial v}=\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial v\partial u}
$$
and similarly for $y$, so the system is well posed. The question is, is it possible to write down a general solution for $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$ in terms of integrals of $f$ ?

If I try, for instance, to integrate the first equation to get
$$
x=\int \mathrm{d}u\;f\cos(u-v)+g(v),
$$ with $g(v)$ some unknown function of $v$, and then plug in the second equation for $x$, I cannot solve for $g(v)$, so I need to try some other ansatz.

Comment: Are these really the equations you want to consider? It would look more nice and symmetric if the derivatives of $x,y$ with respect to $u$ involved derivatives of $f$ with respect to $u$ just as the derivatives of $x,y$ with respect to $v$ involve derivatives of $f$ with respect to $v$. In that case it seems really promising to complexify the equation by defining $z \equiv x + i y, w \equiv u + i v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows: Start with any values for $(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$, say
$$ (x,y)(0,0) = (x_0,y_0). $$
Integrate the first and third equations along the line $v = 0$:
\begin{align*}
x(u,0) &= x_0 + \int_{s=0}^{s=u} f(s,0)\cos(s)\,ds\\
y(u,0) &= y_0 + \int_{s=0}^{s=u} f(s,0)\sin(s)\,ds
\end{align*}
Next, for each $u$, integrate the second and fourth equations along the line $(u,\cdot)$ to get your solution:
\begin{align*}
x(u,v) &= x(u,0) + \int_{t=0}^{t=v} \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(u,t)\sin(u-t)\,dt\\\
y(u,v) &= y(u,0) + \int_{t=0}^{t=v} \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u,t)\cos(u-t)\,dt.
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks for the analysis. I would like to observe the following. If we take $x(u,v)-x_{0}=\int^{u}dt\:f(t,v)\cos(t-v)$ then it satisfies the 1st eqtn. Now, $\partial x(u,v)/\partial v=\int^{u}dt\:\partial\left(f(t,v)\cos(t-v)\right)/\partial v=\int^{u}dt\:\partial\Big(\partial f(t,v)/\partial v\sin(t-v)\Big)/\partial t=\partial f(u,v)/\partial v\sin(u-v)$, then both equations are satisfied (similarly for $y(u,v)$) so by construction the solution should be just $x(u,v)-x_{0}=\int^{u}dt\:f(t,v)\cos(t-v)$, isn't it ? (By $\int^{u}$ I mean integration without evaluating a lower limit).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by integration without evaluating a lower limit. That's not a well-defined function.

Comment: I mean $\int^t dt' \:\partial f(t',s)/\partial t'\equiv f(t,s)$. (This notation is, by the way, a common practice in physics)

Comment: This appears to be the indefinite integral, which means that the right side should be written $f(t,s) + C$, since adding any constant to $f$ also gives an antiderivative of $\partial f(t',s)/\partial t'$. The value of this constant is important in the formulas for the solution.

Comment: exactly, so I'm setting this value of $C$ to zero in my previous comment. My reasoning is this: the solution is unique up to an additive constante, so if I manage to find  $one$ solution this is $the$ solution. Now, by the Leibniz rule the solution in my previous comment seems to satisfy the system, but I'm trying to check if this is the same that you kindly sketched.

Comment: Yes. You should check the details carefully. I’m pretty sure what you’re doing doesn’t work.

Comment: In the second set of integrals it’s important to note that the constant depends on $u$.